# SQL statement - get 1st minimum then 2nd minimum from join

Tags: sql, database, group-by, pivot, window-functions

sorry for terrible description but I have struggled to word this

My 2 tables are like this

tblParent..

```
OrderID  Customer
789      Bob
```

tblChild

```
OrderID  SortOrder  Price
789      1          20.00           
789      3          30.00
```

I want the output of my statement to be
OrderID (From tblParent), Customer (from tblParent), Price1 (this will be   20.00 because it's the 1st price (based on SortOrder) from tblChild), Price2  (this will be 30.00 because its the next highest SortOrder for this OrderID in tblChild

I have tried..

```
SELECT A.OrderID, A.Customer, B.Price, C.Price
FROM tblParent
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Price from tblChild) B on A.OrderID=B.OrderID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Price from tblChild) C on A.OrderID=B.OrderID
```

I know I need to put `MIN()` in somewhere for the 1st price (20.00) but then how do I go about getting the price for the 2nd minimum SortOrder?

I was doing `WHERE SortOrder=1` then for the next column `WHERE SortOrder=2` and so on but then I realised if someone deleted a line from the childtable then `SortOrder` loses its sequence (so in the example, line 2 was deleted and thats why its 1 followed by 3).

Really hope someone can help please. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions and conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT p.OrderID, p.Customer,
       MAX(c.PRICE),
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN C.Price END) as price_2
FROM tblParent p LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT c.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderId ORDER BY SortOrder) as seqnum 
      FROM tblChild c
     ) c 
     ON p.OrderID = c.OrderID
GROUP BY p.OrderID, p.Customer;
```

Comment: Amazing thank you so much! Took a little while to get my head around but got there in the end and it works perfectly. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

If your database (which you did not tag) supports window functions, you can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select
    orderID,
    customer,
    max(case when rn = 1 then price end) price1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then price end) price2
from (
    select
        p.orderID,
        p.customer,
        c.sortOrder,
        c.price,
        row_number() over(partition by c.orderID order by c.sortOrder) rn
    from tblParent p
    inner join tblChild c on c.orderID = p.orderID
) t
group by orderID, customer
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, I went with Gordons answer as it looked a little more what I'm used to with the left join but I'm sure yours would have worked just as well. thanks again!